# Can't find hrefs of interest with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to collect a list of hrefs from the Netflix careers site: https://jobs.netflix.com/search. Each job listing on this site has an anchor and a class: `<a class=css-2y5mtm essqqm81>`. To be thorough here, the entire anchor is:

```
<a class="css-2y5mtm essqqm81" role="link" href="/jobs/244837014" aria-label="Manager, Written Communications"\>\
<span tabindex="-1" class="css-1vbg17 essqqm80"\>\<h4 class="css-hl3xbb e1rpdjew0"\>Manager, Written Communications\</h4\>\</span\>\</a\>
```

Again, the information of interest here is the hrefs of the form `href="/jobs/244837014"`. However, when I perform the standard BS commands to read the HTML:

```
html_page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://jobs.netflix.com/search")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
```

I don't see any of the hrefs that I'm interested in inside of `soup`.

Running the following loop does not show the hrefs of interest:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is being fed dynamically in page, via XHR calls. You need to scrape the API endpoint to get jobs info. The following code will give you a dataframe with all jobs currently listed by Netflix:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm ## if Jupyter: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'referer': 'https://jobs.netflix.com/search',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
big_df = pd.DataFrame()
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for x in tqdm(range(1, 20)):
    url = f'https://jobs.netflix.com/api/search?page={x}'
    r = s.get(url)
    df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['records']['postings'])
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(big_df[['text', 'team', 'external_id', 'updated_at', 'created_at', 'location', 'organization' ]])
```

Result:

```
100%
19/19 [00:29<00:00, 1.42s/it]
text    team    external_id updated_at  created_at  location    organization
0   Events Manager - SEA    [Publicity] 244936062   2022-11-23T07:20:16+00:00   2022-11-23T04:47:29Z    Bangkok, Thailand   [Marketing and PR]
1   Manager, Written Communications [Publicity] 244837014   2022-11-23T07:20:16+00:00   2022-11-22T17:30:06Z    Los Angeles, California [Marketing and Publicity]
2   Manager, Creative Marketing - Korea [Marketing] 244740829   2022-11-23T07:20:16+00:00   2022-11-22T07:39:56Z    Seoul, South Korea  [Marketing and PR]
3   Administrative Assistant - Philippines  [Netflix Technology Services]   244683946   2022-11-23T07:20:16+00:00   2022-11-22T01:26:08Z    Manila, Philippines [Corporate Functions]
4   Associate, Studio FP&A - APAC   [Finance]   244680097   2022-11-23T07:20:16+00:00   2022-11-22T01:01:17Z    Seoul, South Korea  [Corporate Functions]
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
365 Software Engineer (L4/L5) - Content Engineering [Core Engineering, Studio Technologies] 77239837    2022-11-23T07:20:31+00:00   2021-04-22T07:46:29Z    Mexico City, Mexico [Product]
366 Distributed Systems Engineer (L5) - Data Platform   [Data Platform] 201740355   2022-11-23T07:20:31+00:00   2021-03-12T22:18:57Z    Remote, United States   [Product]
367 Senior Research Scientist, Computer Graphics / Computer Vision / Machine Learning   [Data Science and Engineering]  227665988   2022-11-23T07:20:31+00:00   2021-02-04T18:54:10Z    Los Gatos, California   [Product]
368 Counsel, Content - Japan    [Legal and Public Policy]   228338138   2022-11-23T07:20:31+00:00   2020-11-12T03:08:04Z    Tokyo, Japan    [Corporate Functions]
369 Associate, FP&A [Financial Planning and Analysis]   46317422    2022-11-23T07:20:31+00:00   2017-12-26T19:38:32Z    Los Angeles, California [Corporate Functions]
370 rows × 7 columns
```

​
For each job, the url would be `https://jobs.netflix.com/jobs/{external_id}`

Comment: Thanks for the response, Barry. I'm getting an error at the instantiation of the for loop: `tqdm(range(1, 20))`. The error is: 
`ImportError: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html`

I'm not using jupyter so am surprised to see that mentioned. I think its worth pointing out that your comment at the beginning is the exact same as what is actually being imported: 
`from tqdm.notebook import tqdm ## if Jupyter: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm`. Perhaps there is an issue there?

Comment: Okay, I've determined that line 4 needs to be replaced with `from tqdm import tqdm ` and then everything works smoothly!  Thanks for your help! Do you want to edit your original comment to reflect that and then I'll accept the answer? Side note, I don't think BS is used here so I think we can safely remove that import.

Comment: I have a couple of follow-up questions for you so I can understand better.
1) How did you know that `url = f'https://jobs.netflix.com/api/search?page={x}'` was the appropriate API path? is that public information somewhere that I could have found on my own?
2) There are currently 19 pages of job listings available on the website. I noticed you set the max iteration on the for loop to 20. Is it possible to force that number to be based on how many pages are available at any given time (instead of hardcoding the number 20)?

Comment: Edited the tqdm import (code was tested in a Jupyter notebook prior to posting it). BeautifulSoup import has its reasons: the JSON response contains a HTML value (job details which I left out of the dataframe) - you might want to extract that, and then you need to parse it. Yes, there are ways to do a `while` loop over an unknown number of pages, or get that max number from an initial call to the HTML page, then access the API. API endpoint was determined by inspecting the Network tab under browser's Dev tools. @JohnD'Uva